# Why doesn't dist-upgrade upgrade to stretch?

Tags: raspbian, update, pi-b+

I have an old Model B+ (I found out by [checking this page](https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2012/09/checking-your-raspberry-pi-board-version/) – my hardware revision code is 0010), which I'm trying to upgrade to the latest Raspbian. I take it from [the answers to this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/71527/raspberry-pi-1-model-b-end-of-life) that it should be possible to run Stretch on my device. But nothing happens when i do `dist-upgrade`, no errors, just `0 upgraded`.

Any ideas? This is what it looks like when I run the commands I figure are relevant:

```
pi@halle:~ $ cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
pi@halle:~ $ sudo apt-get update
Hit http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie InRelease                                   
Hit http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie InRelease                               
Hit http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/main armhf Packages
Hit http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/ui armhf Packages
Hit http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/main armhf Packages                                     
Hit http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/contrib armhf Packages                                  
Hit http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/non-free armhf Packages
Hit http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/rpi armhf Packages                                      
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/main Translation-en_US                                                                                                                                
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/main Translation-en                                                                                                                                   
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/main Translation-en_US.UTF-8                                                                                                                          
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/ui Translation-en_US                                                                                                                                  
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/ui Translation-en                                                                                                                                     
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org jessie/ui Translation-en_US.UTF-8                                                                                                                            
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/contrib Translation-en_US                                                                                                                         
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/contrib Translation-en                                                                                                                            
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/contrib Translation-en_US.UTF-8                                                                                                                   
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/main Translation-en_US                                                                                                                            
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/main Translation-en                                                                                                                               
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/main Translation-en_US.UTF-8                                                                                                                      
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/non-free Translation-en_US                                                                                                                        
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/non-free Translation-en                                                                                                                           
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/non-free Translation-en_US.UTF-8                                                                                                                  
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/rpi Translation-en_US                                                                                                                             
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/rpi Translation-en                                                                                                                                
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/rpi Translation-en_US.UTF-8                                                                                                                       
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                                                                                   
pi@halle:~ $ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 1):

In your apt sources list it's only looking at the Jessie repository not stretch so it won't pick up any stretch updates. To update you have to change the repository to stretch. You can find instructions on which ones to change here. [Jessie to Stretch Update](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/raspbian-stretch/)

Comment: Thanks! This sounds like the correct answer, but it probably won't have time to try it until next weekend or so, I don't dare to accept the answer yet.